# How to delete files older than 30 days with robocopy?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, synchronization, robocopy

I have two folders synchronised with robocopy (src and mirror) and I try to not removing files in the mirror before 30 days. I tried with `/MINAGE` option to say "consider every files older than 30 days" so that it only deletes 30-day old files in the mirror but it seems that it is only acting on available files (not deleted).

`robocopy /MIR /MINAGE:30 /SD:src /DD:mirror`

So basically, if I create a new file, it will be correctly synced in the mirror (by another robocopy task that doesn't delete files at all); and if the day after I delete it, the file will be deleted in the mirror too when running the previous command. To summarize, I want to delete files deleted in the src folder and older than 30 days in the mirror.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to do it with robocopy, but when I wanted to do the same as what you're doing, I put this line in  my batch file:

`forfiles -p %_BACKUPPATH% -m *.rar -d -3 -c "cmd /c del @path"`

A dissection is:

- `forfiles` - The program for filtering the files
- `-p %_BACKUPPATH%` - `-p` indicates "path" (mine is `%_BACKUPPATH%` but you can replace this with a "real" path), otherwise it uses the current directory
- `-m *.rar` - filter by filetype `.rar`, skip this parameter for `*.*`
- `-d -3` - Only affect files older than 3 days (`-3`)
- `-c "cmd /c del @path"` - anything after the `-c` is what will be executed for each file it finds, in this case, `del`.

Comment: Good to know, but I will delete any file older than 3 days. This in not exactly what I want, I just want to delete files deleted in the src folder since n days.

Comment: @Julio - and I take it the `/mir` switch isn't doing this for you?

Comment: No. I synced a new file file first, then I deleted it in the src folder and I ran the previous command with /mir and /minage:30 expecting a "delete files older than 30 days" behavior but it does not.